# SessionScoped controller not working

Tags: jsf, session, jakarta-ee, javabeans

EDIT:
Okay, so I tried setting a few console.writes to check what's happening... It seems my logout script is called upon navigation. But I don't call it anywhere except on my logout button.

Here is my template code:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#{root}index.xhtml">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#{root}races/list.xhtml">Races</a></li>
            <li><a href="#{root}horses/list.xhtml">Horses</a></li>
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{memberController.logged == true}">
                <li><a href="#{root}profile/history.xhtml">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="#{memberController.logout()}">Logout</a></li>
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{memberController.logged == false}">
                <li><a href="#{root}users/login.xhtml">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#{root}users/register.xhtml">Create Account</a></li>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Original message:

I'm creating a website for my school project (Java EE)... It's our first year doing so.
Now as this is evening school and only had a semester learning it, you might see that my way of doing things ain't the best out there :)

So to get started, I'm trying to create a *login feature* but instead of those hundered lines of security codes, we may use a *simple session scoped member object*.

So here you have a few of my classes:

**Member class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "members")
public class Member implements Serializable {
    //+ Getters, setters, HashCode and equals

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private long id;
    private double money;

    @NotNull(message = "Username cannot be null")
    @Size(min = 4, message = "Username should be of minimum 4 characters")
    private String userName;

    @NotNull(message = "Password cannot be null")
    @Size(min = 4, message = "Password should be of minimum 4 characters")
    private String password;

    @PostPersist
    private void initDefault() {
        this.money = 500;
    }
}
```

**MemberBean class:**

```
@Stateless
public class MemberBean {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="HorseRacingPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public Member getMember(long id){
        return em.find(Member.class, id);
    }

    public Member getMember(String username, String password){
        TypedQuery<Member> q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Member u WHERE u.userName=?1 AND u.password=?2", Member.class);
        q.setParameter(1, username);
        q.setParameter(2, password);
        return q.getSingleResult();
    }

    public List<Member> getAllMembers(){
        TypedQuery<Member> q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Member u", Member.class);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public Member addOrUpdateMember(Member u){
        Member original = em.find(Member.class, u.getId());
        if(original == null){
            em.persist(u);
            return u;
        }else{
            return em.merge(u);
        }
    }

    public Member deleteMember(long id){
        Member original = em.find(Member.class, id);
        if(original != null){
            em.remove(original);
        }
        return original;
    }
}
```

**MemberController class:**

```
@SessionScoped
public class MemberController implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private MemberBean bean;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Member member;
    private boolean logged = false;
// + their getters and setters

    public List<Member> getAllMembers() {
        return bean.getAllMembers();
    }

    public String login() {
        member = bean.getMember(username, password);
        if (member != null) {
            logged = true;
            return "/races/list.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        }
        return "/users/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String logout() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        return "/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public void checkLogin(ComponentSystemEvent e) {
        if (!logged) {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            ConfigurableNavigationHandler handler = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler) context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
            handler.performNavigation("/users/login.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
        }
    }

    public Member getMember() {
        return member;
    }

    public void submit() {
        bean.addOrUpdateMember(member);
    }
}
```

The *main error* I'm getting is the following:

> INFO: Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.

A more specific detail error can be found here: http://pastebin.com/h5nTNnes

So what happens is that when I login, everything works great. The moment I *navigate* to another url (after being forwarded to /races/list) I get *logged out*. The error itself shows when I use the checkLogin():

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{memberController.checkLogin}" />
```

I'm not sure whether this is related, but when I login without any demo data (or with wrong credentials) I get an evaluation exception and that no entity could be retrieved.
Here more details: http://pastebin.com/Tv9mQ1K9

What could this be? I scratched my head for 3 days now and can't seem to find an issue anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the section [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) in the FAQ and rewrite your question, otherwise it would be closed (and maybe downvoted).

Comment: I've read it but can't seem to see what problem there is with my question. I know there are more than 2 links, but it's to make sure the text ain't to long to read and that people can actually organize their tabs to look in the code instead of scrolling several times up and down.

Comment: That's the problem: you have to write all the relevate code in the question and don't point to external links that shows your code. Try to minimize the code to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) in order that we could understand it and help you. Remember that this site is for **free** advice, not a Java EE support team that will give everything in their hands to satisfy your needs at all cost.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I hope this edit fixes it. I did however included the error details as link but gave a small summary on what I think might be the error. To lessen the code, I removed all imports and getters and setters but said so in the comments.

Comment: K I edited my post, as it seems the logout script is being called after navigation (when logged in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This,

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="#{memberController.logout()}">Logout</a></li>
```

is not right.

The `onclick` attribute should reference a JavaScript handler. E.g. `alert('peek-a-boo');`. JSF/EL treats it as a plain vanilla string and expects that the `logout()` method returns some JavaScript code as `String` which should then be inlined in the HTML result. Imagine that the method actually returned `alert('peek-a-boo');`, then the final result (as you see in browser by rightclick, *View Source*) would be this:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="alert('peek-a-boo');">Logout</a></li>
```

However, in your particular case you're actually performing a logout and returning a string value of `/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true`. So the generated HTML ends up being

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">Logout</a></li>
```

Which is invalid JS code. But that's not the major problem: the user is been logged out without clicking the link!

You need a fullworthy JSF command component instead. E.g. `<h:commandLink>`.

```
<li><h:form><h:commandLink value="Logout" action="#{memberController.logout()}"/></h:form></li>
```

The method is this way only invoked when the link is actually clicked, which is exactly what you need.

Comment: Waw a million thanks for the solution and explanations onto why this is happening! it works great!